# Windows 7 file copy: Setting to ask about overwriting files / merging folders BEFORE copy starts?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer

I am not expecting there to be a registry setting or way to do this, but is it possible (without a third-party filecopy handler) to **have windows search for conflicting folder or file names before the copying process begins**, so I don't have to monitor the copy process?

I like how in Windows 7 it waits until all non-conflicting files are copied before asking, but it would be nicer if all the questions were asked in the beginning so the copy process can proceed uninterrupted. This gets extremely burdensome when copying hundreds of gigabytes and needing to be present for when that dialog finally pops up.

Comment: I use robocopy regularly with external drives over USB, networks, fat32, exfat, ntfs. Maybe post a question on the issues you're having with robocopy? It's a great tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the copy option in the command line?. With the help of default Microsoft Windows 'Copy' command, you can suppress prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file using the argument /Y

By doing this way, you will not prompted to give your input and the copy process will not need your intervention.

```
c\> copy /Y c:\dir1\subdir1\file1.txt  c:\dir2\subdir2\file2.txt
```

If the destination file exists, the above command overwrites the same without asking the user for confirmation

Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks like the best option for those big jobs where it could take hours. Thanks!